# Can't link NASM built assembly with gcc on a 64 bit machine to a 32 bit executable on Windows

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, mingw, nasm

I've started learning assembly, like the one that compiles, because I was very familiar how assembly works in pure programs, but wanted to be able to write them too.
I chose NASM. It seems to support a lot of systems and architectures, so as I understood I need elf32 or win32 object file in order to link it using the ld or gcc linkers. The problem is it says I don't have libraries to link it properly. I went to google it and found out that I need to install these libraries to change --target and finally link them, the problem is that these libraries are linux only, there are no MinGW package or zip file to download for windows. How do I get them? Or am I wrong in some case?
Same results with elf and win32
The error message is:
ld: i386 architecture of input file `test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Comment: You seem to have a 64 bit `ld`. Use the appropriate emulation to switch it to 32 bit mode. Probably `-m i386pe`.

Comment: oh, that does work, but I can't seem to link windows libraries. Ok, I think I can figure this one next...

Comment: It seems to work with golink using win32, but I wanted to do elf32 and then link it with ld or gcc linkers, but it says it can't find references to win functions...(both .obj and .o), how can I link kernel32.dll?